# AngularJS add exceptions to html

Tags: html, angularjs, bind

I have a big problem, how do I make Angular interpret only html
Example

```
ng-bing-html="<notthis> <br> <notthis>"
```

How can I make it to show like this with the arrows

```
<notthis>
<notthis>
```

Comment: what is `<notthis>` ? If it is a directive `ng-bind-html` doesn't compile directives because that's not what it is used for. Question is sadly lacking in proper problem description details

Comment: <notthis> is a random strin that i want to put inside <>

Comment: And how is that very brief comment supposed to help us understand your problem? If you want help here, you need to put a little more effort in

Answer (score 0):

If you know which are real tags/directives and which not:

- leave the real ones as they are;
- on the "fake" tags change `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;`.

I mean:

```
ng-bing-html="&lt;notthis&gt; <br> &lt;notthis&gt;"
```

It will work.